# Trigger Tabs only on certain screen size

Tags: jquery

Having some problems getting tabs to only trigger when viewed on an iPhone (basically max-wdith:740px).

I've tried a number of options, but can't seem to get it to work. This is my basic jQuery:

---

```
$('#tab-1, #tab-2, #tab-3').hide();
$('#tab-1').show();
$('ul.mobileTabs li a.mobiletab1').addClass('mobileActive');

$('ul.mobileTabs li a').click(function(){
    $('ul.mobileTabs li').removeClass('mobileActive');
    $(this).parent().addClass('mobileActive');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tab-1, #tab-2, #tab-3').hide();
    $(currentTab).show();
    return false;
});
```

---

Be great if someone could help me!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

iPhone size in pixel for responsive design is 300px for Portrait and 420px for landscape.

If you want to run function only for a certain browser size you can do this:

```
if($(window).width() <= 740) {
   foo();
} else {
   boo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this -> `$('ul.mobileTabs li').addClass('mobileActive');`?

```
$('#tab-1, #tab-2, #tab-3').hide();
$('#tab-1').show();
$('ul.mobileTabs li').addClass('mobileActive');
```

The dom added class "mobileActive" should be "li"